# Truncate text in div with dynamic width and height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Since I've very little code I'll copy it below:

```
<!doctype html>

    <head>

        <style>

            #box{

                position:absolute;
                border:2px solid #CCC;
                width:calc(50vw - 6px);
                height:calc(33vw + 67px);
                overflow:hidden;
           }

       </style>

    </head>


    <body>

        <div id = "box"> A whole lot of text </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

As you can see I have a div (`box`) which has dynamic width and height. I've hidden the overflow, but I'd like some sort of way to hide the last line instead of only showing half the line, in some cases.

Also, an ellipsis would be nice, but I've tried `text-overflow: ellipsis`, which only seems to work when the text doesn't wrap.

This is not as necessity but I can't imagine why it wouldn't be possible.

Everything I've found online seems to work with fixed height. Any idea how I might approach this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm probably entirely wrong, but try adding this to the css:

```
direction: rtl;
```

Personally, I would try putting it inside a **table**, a table should handle the text wrapping and the fixed height issue you don't want to set.

Comment: No luck there unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

If multi line ellipsis solves your problem, I have a way out for you...

```
.line-clamp { display: -webkit-box; -webkit-line-clamp: 3; -webkit-box-orient: vertical; }
```

PS: browser specific implementation, works only for chrome...